# Selecting from table a and using result to retrieve inverse from tableb

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables.

- Rooms contains: Room 111, Room 102, Room 201, Room 122
- Booking contains: Room 102, Room 201

If I issue the following SQL statement:

```
Select roomname from Booking where checkin='12/03/2014' and checkout='15/03/2014'
```

I get two rows

- Room 102
- Room 201

I want to use these rows to get all other roomnames in Rooms table, apart from Room 102 and Room 201.

Here is my Code:

```
   $a1=12/03/2014
   $a2=15/03/2014
   $sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Booking WHERE checkin = '$a1' AND  checkout ='$a2'");
   while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
   {
      $pid = $myrow["roomname"];
      $sql1= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Rooms WHERE roomname != '$pid'");
      while($me = mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
      {
         $pid2 = $me["roomname"];
         echo $pid2;      
      }//
   }//end while
```

I will get two set of results, the first containing Room 201 and the second containing Room 102:

```
Room 111 Room 201 Room122
Room 111 Room 102 Room122
```

I just want one result not containing Room 201 and Room 102:

```
Room 111 and Room 102
```

Comment: Nice question! Very clear and well explained. One thing to note that may make future posts easier in terms of your layout: when you are entering a question, there are a bunch of buttons just above the text box. I used two of them to clean up your layout a little bit, the "bullet points" button (it looks like a list with bullet points) and the "format as code" button (it looks like a pair of curly braces). In particular with a large code block like you have, it is clearer to read if you format the whole block (rather than surrounding each individual line with backquotes). Keep posting!

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following query:

```
SELECT roomname FROM Booking WHERE roomname NOT IN (SELECT roomname FROM Booking WHERE checkin = '12/03/2014' AND checkout = '15/03/2014');
```

or at least it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: This is a good general approach, but one additional comment: it looks like you are using "roomname" as your primary key value for the Rooms table? If so, you'd be better off with a made-up key value (like an AUTO_INCREMENT field) -- user-facing data (like a room name) can tend to change over time, and since primary key values should never change, that is why made-up values are better. Plus the compactness of a numeric key value has some performance advantages.

Comment: Thanks for that addition. Since we didn't know anything about the actual table structure it was difficult to create a better query. Of course numeric/primary key ids are much more performant and should be used whenever possible.

Comment: "roomname" is not primary key

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just do something like:

```
SELECT Rooms.* FROM Rooms
LEFT JOIN Booking
ON Rooms.roomname = Booking.roomname 
WHERE checkin != '12/03/2014' AND checkout != '15/03/2014';
```

Comment: Thanks but and getting this Error

Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in